# How to write single objectMapper for spring-data-rest and to my @RestController class

Tags: serialization, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, jackson2

I wrote a UnwrappingBeanSerializer for my entity. Currently this serializer was registered using [ConfigureJacksonObjectMapper](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter.html#configureJacksonObjectMapper-com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper-)

This serializer is working fine for REST APIs generated from spring-data-rest. But I have a custom `@RestController` for the same entity, But it doesn't know about the serializer registered in spring-data-rest configuration.

I want to serialize my response with `UnwrappingBeanSerializer` both in spring-data-rest APIs and also to my custom controllers.

How to achieve this?

I also tried with `@JsonSerialize` on my entity class. But I am unable to create bean for `unWrappingBeanSerializer` with `BeanSerializerBase`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular `@RestController` and `Spring Data REST` controllers have different flows and configuration. If you are using `Spring Data REST`, you'd better use `@RepositoryRestController` for custom endpoints of the same resource, this will use the same `Spring Data REST` chain and its configuration, like the one you used in [ConfigureJacksonObjectMapper](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter.html#configureJacksonObjectMapper-com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper-), otherwise your `ObjectMapper` is visible only for `Spring Data REST`.

If you want to have `@RestController` and use the same `ObjectMapper` for both - you need to have two configurations: one for `Spring Data REST` (like you already have) and another for regular controllers, so just register it in Spring context (for instance, if you are using Spring MVC, see [Customize the Jackson ObjectMapper](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper)).